# Getting a specific IPs with regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex, ip, expression, oid

I'm working on some logs right now and I have a problem that I couldn't resolve yet.

I want to find with regular expression all the ips in each line in my log file.

My problem is, that I have something unique in this logs, called oid that most of the times is written like this (the numbers are an example): `oid: 1.3.2.4.5.3.2.4.2.2.`

As I watched in my logs, the numbers are various and sometimes I can get a lines like:

`oid: 1.3.2.4.512.3.2.434.2.2.`

As you can understand, my regular expression finds this oid (which is not an ip) and causes me a lot of problems.

Can someone give me a regular expression that will fix this problem?

** I used this regex to find ips in line: `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}`

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some lookarounds to help make sure there are no other `.` around the IP:

```
(?<!\.)\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b(?!\.\d)
```

`(?<!\.)` makes sure there's no dot before the IP and `(?!\.\d)` makes sure there's no `.` after the IP and a number. I added a number because I think you could have an IP followed by a dot if that last dot is meant to be the period of the end of a sentence.

The word boundaries (`\b`) prevent matching between numbers.

Comment: on python 3 `ipaddress.ip_address()` that can be used to check results (raises `ValueError` if string is not IP4 or IP6 address).

Comment: Well, it didn't work.

for this line:

'oid: 1.3.2.4.512.3.2.434.2.2. ip = 190.80.3.25\123'
The regex found ['12.3.2.43', '190.80.3.25'] as ips.

More answers please..

(Oh, and i am using python 2.7.5 in my office, so python 3 functions are not so relevant, but thanks)

Comment: @chenan Thanks, that example was helpful :) I updated the regex. There was one more thing to use.

Comment: @Jerry I tried this experssion you wrote: '(?<!\.)\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b(?!\.\d)' and it didn't find ips in my line at all.
Can you improve this? Thx

Comment: @chenan Are you rawing your regex string? By that, I mean using `r`. `results = re.findall(r'[put regex here]', file)`

Comment: @Jerry Of Course.
This is what i wrote:
re.findall(r'{}'.format(A),a) When A=Regex and a=line.

Comment: @chenan But are you rawing `A`? If the substitution of backslashes occurred before putting it in the regex, then it doesn't matter if you raw the one in the `findall`. Also, here's a test on [ideone](http://ideone.com/LhvYyi).